# `heroku run rake db:migrate` fails with error `R99` from yesterday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've tried `heroku run rake db:migrate` and get `Connection timed out` error.

Adn `heroku logs` shows this error.

> 2013-10-18T10:07:20.765963+00:00 heroku[run.5173]: Awaiting client
>   2013-10-18T10:07:30.324619+00:00 heroku[run.5173]: Error R99 (Platform
>   error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
>   2013-10-18T10:07:30.324809+00:00 heroku[run.5173]: Stopping process
>   with SIGKILL 2013-10-18T10:07:50.767590+00:00 heroku[run.5173]: Error
>   R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
>   2013-10-18T10:07:51.840739+00:00 heroku[run.5173]: Process exited with
>   status 128 2013-10-18T10:07:30.363887+00:00 heroku[run.5173]: State
>   changed from starting to complete

According to the document, there is nothing that I can do with `R99` error, except for waiting.

But I've been trying the command from yesterday, and still getting errors.
What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: This could be happening because your application is referencing another unavailable service during startup.  Do you know if that's the case?

Comment: I can't quite understand about "referencing another unavailable service". Can you tell me some examples?

Comment: For example it waits for Redis connection that is not yet available. R99 doesn't happen for no reason, I am pretty sure that your app starts up very slowly.